# Saving first selected option of a checkbox array

Tags: javascript, loops

Assuming I have a `checkbox` array which allows multiple selections to be made. I would like to save only the first selection in a variable but still record and save the other selections (in another variable). Something like :

```
First_Selected = this_selection (x)
Other_Selected = these_selections(1,2,3)
```

Using the loop below how would I achieve this??

```
   var Selection_one = " ";
    var other_Selections = " ";
    for (i = 0; i < tbls.length; i++) {
        Selection_one = ?? ;
        other_Selections += ?? ;
    }
```

Comment: what is tbls here, it is checkbox itself? and why don't you think about if i == 1 and save it to first

Comment: `tbls` is an array that I store checked values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your logic

```
var Selection_one = " ";
    var other_Selections = " ";
    for (i = 0; i < tbls.length; i++) {
       if(i == 0)
           Selection_one = tbls[i];
        other_Selections += tbls[i] + ',' ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.slice()` to select all the elements after the first one, and then use `.join()` to concatenate all the values.

```
var selection_one = tbls[0];
var other_selections = tbls.slice(1).join(' ');
```